# Tensor product of holomorphic functions and density

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$ be two open subsets of $\mathbb{C}.$

Is the image of $$\Phi : \mathcal{O}(\Omega_1) \times \mathcal{O}(\Omega_2) \to \mathcal{O}(\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2), (f,g)\mapsto ((z,w) \mapsto f(z)g(w))$$ dense in $\mathcal{O}(\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2)$ ? (Here the topology is the uniform convergence on compact subsets.)

I know the result for test functions but I wonder if it is true for holomorphic functions. Maybe with some extra-conditions on the open subsets ? Thanks for any help/suggestion.

Comment: If you mean $\mathcal{O}(\Omega_1) \otimes \mathcal{O}(\Omega_2)$ (the vector space generated by the $f(z)g(w)$) then yes at least for simply connected domains

Comment: @reuns : Thank you. Can you give me some ideas of the proof, please ?

Answer (score 2):

If $\Omega_1,\Omega_2$ are bounded open with finite length boundary.

For a compact subset $K$ of $\Omega_1\times \Omega_2$, pick two simple closed curves $A_i \subset \Omega_i$ such that $Int(A_1)\times Int(A_2)$ contains $K$. For $(z,w) \in Int(A_1)\times Int(A_2)$

$$ f(z,w) =\frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{A_1} \frac{f(s,w)}{s-z} ds=\frac{1}{(2i\pi)^2}\int_{A_1} \int_{A_2} \frac{f(s,u)}{(s-z)(u-w)} dsdu$$

Approximating $\int_{A_1} \int_{A_2} $ with a Riemann sum yields 
$$f(z,w) \approx \frac{1}{(2i\pi)^2}\sum_{i=1}^I\sum_{j=1}^J \frac{f(s_j,u_i)}{(s_j-z)(u_i-w)} (s_{j+1}-s_j)(u_{i+1}-u_i)$$

Taking $A_1$ very close to $\partial \Omega_1$ we can take $\widetilde{s_j} \not \in \Omega_1$ very close to $s_j$  so that

$$f(z,w) \approx \frac{1}{(2i\pi)^2}\sum_{i=1}^I\sum_{j=1}^J \frac{f(s_j,u_i)}{(\widetilde{s_j}-z)(\widetilde{u_i}-w)} (s_{j+1}-s_j)(u_{i+1}-u_i) \in \mathcal{O}(\Omega_1) \otimes \mathcal{O}(\Omega_2)$$

Comment: Thank you for this answer. As I feared, the conditions on the open subsets are very restrictive.